# Mockito: Expected exception in asynchronous callback

Tags: java, unit-testing, asynchronous, junit, mockito

I'm creating a database wrapper. This wrapper has a series of states:

- it is created
- you are signing in
- you are signed id
- you are connected to a specific table

Methods on my database wrapper can trigger the state transitions.
But the database interactions are asynchronous, so you don't get immediate feedback. Instead, you can register as a listener for `onStateChanged` events.

I'm using mockito to test the transitions, and so far I'm really amazed at how clean the use of `InOrder` and `verify` are.

But now I'm running into a problem. I'm trying to test a forbidden transition. My Database wrapper will catch that you're not in the correct state and throw an `AssertionException`. This Exception let's the testing crash. I'm trying to register this as an expected exception with Mockito, but I can't figure out how to do this in the correct way.

The following code is all in one function, the exception is expected by JUnit:

```
@Test(expected = AssertionError.class)
public void cantCreateTwice() throws Exception{
    ...
```

First I'm creating a connection, and I'm setting up a StateChangeListener which attempts the forbidden transition:

```
final FirebaseConnection connection = new FirebaseConnection();

StateChangeListener stateChangeListener = new StateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(DBState newState) {
        if(newState==DBState.SignedIn){
            connection.createParty();
            connection.createParty();  // forbidden
        }
    }
};
```

Next, I'm registering this listener and a mock:

```
StateChangeListener mockedListener = mock(StateChangeListener.class);

connection.addStateChangeListener(stateChangeListener);
connection.addStateChangeListener(mockedListener);
```

Then I tell Mockito about the expected exception and start the test:

```
doThrow(new AssertionError()).when(mockedListener).onStateChanged(DBState.SignedIn);

connection.signIn();

verify(mockedListener, times(1)).onStateChanged(DBState.SigninIn);
verify(mockedListener, times(1)).onStateChanged(DBState.SignedIn);
```

This will result in:

> Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process
>   crashed.'

The exception that crashed the process is the expected AssertionError:

> java.lang.AssertionError: the connection is not in the necessary state

I think the problem is that my exception is not triggered when a function is called on the mocked listener, but on the anonymous implementation. 
But I need the anonymous implementation to trigger the forbidden functionality.
I also need the `verify` since my callbacks are asynchronous. If I remove the verify then the test will simply return immediately without any exception being thrown.

It seems to me that I somehow need to convert my anonymous implementation into a Mock object that can be supervised by `Mockito`. But `mock()` doesn't work on anonymous classes. And I think it's not correct to have an individual class for every snippet of logic in my test cases.

How can I tell `Mockito` to expect this exception ?

**EDIT:**

I think I've found a way, I'm using verify with a timeout:

```
verify(mockedListener, timeout(1000).times(1)).onStateChanged(DBState.SigninIn);
verify(mockedListener, timeout(1000).times(1)).onStateChanged(DBState.SignedIn);

connection.createParty();
connection.createParty();
```

This blocks until the sign-in was completed. Then it tries to create a party twice, which fails and throws the expected exception.

But I think I'm now basically misusing a feature of Mockito for synchronization. Is this the correct way to use Mockito for my problem ?

Comment: `doThrow` ask Mockito to throw an exception not to expect one. If I understand well, what you want is probably `doReturn(xxx).doThrow(yyyy).when` to tell mockito to return xxx the first time then throw

Comment: My problem is that I have two stateChangeListeners. One of them is the real implementation one is a mock. I‘m using the mock to record what has happened. And in this case, after the sign-in, there is an exception. But that exception is not thrown when the method is called on the mock. It occurs when the method is called on the actual object. So during the test, before we arrive at this call on the mock, the exception will be thrown and crash mockito. How can I tell mockito that an exception during the test is expected ? I need mockito as a dependency to wait for my callback.

Comment: Do you have `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` in your test? Why do you use instrumented test for typical unit test?

Comment: @Pavel Zorin Yes, I've got @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) in my test class. That's because I have firebase as a dependency. Even after adding all dependencies to testCompile in the gradle file, there where still Unknown Source exceptions. I figured this was because firebase somehow depends on the android environment.